# Python all combinations where letters can go in other list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get all the lists that are possible with a list of letters and a list with empty spaces where the letters can go, example:

```
Input:
letters = ['a', 'b']
playboard = ['', 'c', '']
```

```
Output:
[['', 'c', ''],
 ['a', 'c', ''],
 ['', 'c', 'a']
 ['b', 'c', ''],
 ['', 'c', 'b'],
 ['a', 'c', 'b'],
 ['b', 'c', 'a']]
```

Is this possible?
Thanks for helping!

Comment: Use the module itertools

Comment: Are there always 2 spaces? The `'c'` is a bit of a distraction. I would concentrate on filling lists of spaces with the letters, and then in a subsequent step assemble them into the final list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which will distribute any number of letters into any number of blank positions. It is up to you to distribute the results into the relevant positions in your game board:

```
import itertools

def fill_blanks(num_blanks, letters):
    n = min(num_blanks, len(letters))
    indices = list(range(num_blanks))

    for k in range(n+1):
        for positions in itertools.combinations(indices,k):
            for choices in itertools.permutations(letters,k):
                blanks = ['']*num_blanks
                for i,a in zip(positions,choices):
                    blanks[i] = a
                yield blanks
```

For example,

```
>>> list(fill_blanks(2,['a','b']))
[['', ''], ['a', ''], ['b', ''], ['', 'a'], ['', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'a']]
```

The code itself can be tweaked to directly generate the resulting game boards:

```
def fill_board(board, letters):
    indices = [i for i,c in enumerate(board) if c == '']
    n = min(len(indices),len(board))

    for k in range(n+1):
        for positions in itertools.combinations(indices,k):
            for choices in itertools.permutations(letters,k):
                filled_board = board[:]
                for i,a in zip(positions,choices):
                    filled_board[i] = a
                yield filled_board
```

Then, for example, `list(fill_board(['','c',''],['a','b']))`

Comment: Accepted this one because it is much faster on bigger boards than the other one

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
from itertools import combinations, permutations

def get_all_combinations(letters:list, playboard:list):
    res_all=[]
    cnt=playboard.count('')
    if(cnt==0):
        res_all.append(playboard)
    else:
        for el1 in combinations(letters+['']*cnt, cnt):
            for el2 in permutations(el1):
                i=0
                res=[]
                for a in playboard:
                    if(a==''):
                        res.append(el2[i])
                        i+=1
                    else:
                        res.append(a)
                if (res not in res_all): res_all.append(res)
    return res_all
```

Outputs:

```py
letters = ['a', 'b']
playboard = ['', 'c', '']

>>> get_all_combinations(letters, playboard)

[['a', 'c', 'b'], ['b', 'c', 'a'], ['a', 'c', ''], ['', 'c', 'a'], ['b', 'c', ''], ['', 'c', 'b'], ['', 'c', '']]
```

Comment: Only downside is that it is very slow when doing it on a large playboard (for example 15) (kept this `letters = ['a']` `playboard = ['', '', ...(x15)]` runing for 10 mins (old i7) but it is still not done, only using 15% cpu and 20mb ram)

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import permutations

playboard = ['', 'c', '']
result = [playboard] # Add first element
choices = ['a','b','']
for p in permutations(choices,2): # get all permutations of the available letters
    result.append([p[0],playboard[1],p[1]])
```

Your desired result has the `['','c','']` which doesn't get produced by the permutations as it has 2 repeated values, so you should add that first to the list of elements.

Comment: You will generate 5 combinations that way - the missing one: `['', 'c', '']`